# Why tab bar icon is not showing in my Bar item image?

Tags: ios, swift, icons, resolution, tabbar

I am creating a simple tab bar , and i am using iphone 8 in simulator. I have imported icon( not glyph) of size 50 x 50 as mentioned in apple guideline, but the icon is not showing up in bar item image. I have done everything ( Render as, change pixel size, even i tried with different resolutions like 25 x 25, 75 x 75) but its not showing up in portrait mode. Kindly help. i wanna do it in storyboard. Below are the screenshots. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just typed the image name in the box

[image]

If you want the file showed in the dropdown, **close and reopen** the project so Xcode will do reindexing all project files

Comment: Oh thanks! Typing thing worked for me for 50 x 50 icon.

Comment: If you want, close and reopen project to make xcode reindexing your file so you can see the file in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding the icon into the other 2 slots for universal.